# Does java manipulate the order of keys in map before sending via REST Api?

Tags: java, rest, linkedhashmap

I have a LinkedHashMap which is having key (String) and value (List of some Object) pair. The order of keys is proper till the return statement. After receiving it on UI end the order of keys seems changed.

Is java playing any role here? If yes, how to rectify that? I want same sequence on UI which is returned from database.

Comment: Java will retain the order. Can you share your code that returns the data?

Comment: Please read "How to create a [mcve]". Then use the [edit] link to improve your question (do not add more information via comments). Otherwise we are not able to answer your question and help you.

Comment: can you share the code for Ui and java also

Comment: The core property of a linked hash map is to always iterate its entries based on insertion order. So, using that type is the first step when order matters. But beyond that, we can't help unless you disclose the relevant parts of your code here.

Comment: It probably depends on how your Map is rendered in JSON - as an object (unordered) or an array (ordered). Depending on the JSPN-library you use, it is quite possible that the runtime type of the map is not taken into account.

Comment: Suggest you to check Json which you may be getting in your JS.

Comment: I think I agree with Tarun; an important clue would be to look at the HTTP response directly, because it is rendered in your UI.  You might be able to do that with the UI tooling, or by using raw tooling (curl) to invoke the API "by hand".

Comment: @Tarun I have checked the response of HTTP in my network tab and its correct only (maintaining the insertion order). But the response which is received on UI is having unordered data.

Comment: @schaturv If it is ordered in JSON, Then problem is with _how you use json to show data in UI_

Comment: @Tarun Network tab was showing ordered data but JSON received on JS was unordered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Documentation of [LinkedHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html)**

> Hash table and linked list implementation of the Map interface, with predictable iteration order. This implementation differs from HashMap in that it maintains a doubly-linked list running through all of its entries. **This linked list defines the iteration ordering, which is normally the order in which keys were inserted into the map (insertion-order).** Note that insertion order is not affected if a key is re-inserted into the map. (A key k is reinserted into a map m if m.put(k, v) is invoked when m.containsKey(k) would return true immediately prior to the invocation.)

The `LinkedHashMap` in Java will maintain the ordering for insertion. If you read the key-value pairs from an ordered list and insert this into a `LinkedHashMap` in the same order, then the arrangement will be preserved.

That said, if you're reading this in from a JSON, then the ordering of pairs should be considered un-ordered

**From the JSON specification [RFC 8259](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8259):**

> An object is an unordered collection of zero or more name/value
> pairs, where a name is a string and a value is a string, number,
> boolean, null, object, or array.

Further:

> JSON parsing libraries have been observed to differ as to whether or
> not they make the ordering of object members visible to calling
> software.  Implementations whose behavior does not depend on member
> ordering will be interoperable in the sense that they will not be
> affected by these differences.

If you need a workaround then you can follow the answer provided by [clayton.carmo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3612117/). This workaround works by converting the JSON *object* form into a JSON *array* of key-value objects. This is guaranteed to maintain ordering. From the RFC documentation:

> An array is an ordered sequence of zero or more values.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am using hashmap on my java side to create the object to be returned which is resulting in JSON object. If I need to return JSON array how can I convert that in my java code?

Comment: @schaturv you should be able to turn `Map::entrySet` into a json object

Comment: Yes this is already happening. I am getting that map as a json on UI but I am asking about converting Map to json array format as mentioned above as second option. Since plain json object is not retaining the order.

Comment: @schaturv serializing the entryset is different from serializing the map itself

Answer (score 3):

Even if you send it ordered, the JSON object may not keep the order of the attributes. If you need an ordered sequence of elements, send a list with well defined objects.

For example, instead of this:

```
{
  "0": ["a0", "b0", "c0"],
  "1": ["a1", "b1", "c1"]
}
```

Use something like this:

```
[
  {
    "key": 0,
    "value": ["a0", "b0", "c0"]
  },
  {
    "key": 1,
    "value": ["a1", "b1", "c1"]
  }
]
```

Comment: Indeed. Your first example is a [JSON](https://www.json.org/) object, and that is defined as "An object is an unordered set of name/value pairs." The second one is an array, and as such gurantees order: "An array is an ordered collection of values."